# Array assignment with index only works in curly brackets

Tags: java

I got a weird problem where i cannot assign a value (Object s) via an index to an GameObject array, but when i put the expression in curly brackets it works.
GameObject is an interface and Sphere (Object s) implements it

I have basically tried everything, but as i said, putting the expression in curly brackets works but i want to know why this is like that.

```
Sphere s = new Sphere(new double[] {0,0,50},10,new Color(255,0,0));
GameObject[] objs = new GameObject[5];
objs[0] = s;
```

does not work,

but this works:

```
 Sphere s = new Sphere(new double[] {0,0,50},10,new Color(255,0,0));
 GameObject[] objs = new GameObject[5];
 {objs[0] = s;}
```

I am using the eclipse IDE from December 2018

Comment: Is this inside a method?  Or just in your class, in no particular method?

Comment: I would recommend using a constructor, for all but the most straightforward initialisation.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Please provide a [mcve] that I can copy and paste into my IDE.

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem it works inside a constructor, but i was just initializing it outside for testing purposes

Comment: @JoeC for that i would have to provide 3 java classes if it helps

Comment: To clarify: I'm not asking for your entire assignment.  I'm asking for a small, verifiable example (20 lines or less) that shows the same thing.

Comment: @dani_a_cruel_killer Yes, you can't have arbitrary code outside of any method or constructor.  That's the rules!

Comment: nvm thank you for the solution! i didnt know you cant set the value of an array item outside the constructor

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are attempting something like this.

```
class YourClass {
    Sphere s = new Sphere(new double[] {0,0,50},10,new Color(255,0,0));
    GameObject[] objs = new GameObject[5];
    objs[0] = s;
}
```

That is not allowed in Java. You can only put method declarations and field declarations directly inside classes. You can just put random statements there - they have to be inside a method, constructor, or you put it inside a braces to form an [initializer block](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-26-the-initializer-block-in-java/). This is how you would use such an initializer block.

```
class YourClass {
    GameObject[] objs = new GameObject[5];

    {/* initializer block */
        objs[0] = new Sphere(new double[] {0,0,50},10,new Color(255,0,0));
    }
}
```